# Bot Framework Webchat microphone speech not working in Safari

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I'm have a webchat conrol for a bot that that is up and running and working well in Chrome.
The link [How to enable speech in Web Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#custom-speech-service) shows how to set this up and we have done it exactly like this.

It mentioned multiple browsers, but does not specify Safari in any way.

We need this working on an iPhone, however it just doesn't seem to work, there is not a lot of feedback from the browser, the icon changes and it appears to have turned on the microphone after access is approved.

Nothing spoken is recorded/recognized and the text area of the bot stays empty, no 'listining....' or any other indication its working other than the red microphone on icon in the browser header. clicking the icon mutes and un-mutes as you'd expect, it just doesn't seem to be connected to the webchat control in the browser.

All of my investigation appears to go around in circles.

1. Has anyone achieved this with WebChat, or any other direct line component?
2. Or Can anyone confirm definitely doesn't work with safari so I can stop banging my head against it.
3. Are there any alternatives to webchat that do work in iPhone/Safari?

Thanks for taking the time to read, any assistance would be much appreciated, I'm at the end on this investigation and pulling my hair out.

Comment: Would you please post an issue in the [official webchat repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new) so we can track and look into this for you?  Thank you for reporting this

Comment: There's some info in the issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft mentions that the Safari browser in iOS has special needs in [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/SPEECH.md#notes-3), and it could be the problem that you are facing:

> Safari requires additional permission granted explicitly by the user. The user needs to perform an interaction (click/tap/type) before any audio clips can be played during the browser session.